# Why would I use Perl anonymous subroutines instead of a named one?

Tags: perl, anonymous, subroutine

I'm just curious why one would choose to use an anonymous subroutine, versus a named one, in Perl. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

- You can store anonymous subs in arrays, hashes and scalars.
- You can build them at runtime
- You can pass them as arguments to other functions.
- You get to keep variables in the surrounding scope.

The last point is probably the most important, because it's often the most unexpected facet of named vs. anonymous subroutines in Perl.  Example:

```
sub outer
{
  my $a = 123;

  sub inner
  {
    print $a, "\n";
  }

  # At this point, $a is 123, so this call should always print 123, right?
  inner();

  $a = 456;
}

outer(); # prints 123
outer(); # prints 456! Surprise!
```

But change "inner" from a named subroutine to a reference to an anonymous subroutine and it works is a much less surprising manner:

```
sub outer
{
  my $a = 123;

  my $inner = sub
  {
    print $a, "\n";
  };

  # At this point, $a is 123, and since the anonymous subrotine 
  # whose reference is stored in $inner closes over $a in the 
  # "expected" way...
  $inner->();

  $a = 456;
}

# ...we see the "expected" results
outer(); # prints 123
outer(); # prints 123
```

(Of course, everyone's expectations are different, thus the "scare quotes" around "expected.")

Here's an example use in real code (though it should be noted that the `File::Find` interface is generally considered to be a poor one—due to its use of global variables, not its use of anonymous subroutines):

```
sub find_files
{
  my @files;

  my $wanted = sub
  { 
    if($something)
    {
      push @files, $File::Find::name;
    }
  };

  # The find() function called here is imported from File::Find
  find({ wanted => $wanted }, $directory);

  return @files;
}
```

Passing a named subroutine as the value of the `wanted` parameter would require polluting the namespace with a routine that may only be used once, and defining a named subroutine *within* the `find_files()` subroutine would exhibit the "unexpected" behavior demonstrated earlier.

Comment: Of course, you can store named ('nonymous'?) subs in a variable too...
my $var = \&find_files;

Comment: Of course, I was exaggerating a bit for a more dramatic effect.

Comment: Now Perl has lexical named subroutines. :)

Answer (score 16):

Callbacks and generators come to mind. An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub generate_multiplier {
    my ($coef) = @_;

    return sub { 
        my ($val) = @_;
        $coef * $val;
    }
}

my $doubler = generate_multiplier(2);
my $tripler = generate_multiplier(3);

for my $i ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    printf "%4d%4d%4d\n", $i, $doubler->($i), $tripler->($i);
}

__END__

C:\Temp> v
    1   2   3
    2   4   6
    3   6   9
    4   8  12
    5  10  15
    6  12  18
    7  14  21
    8  16  24
    9  18  27
   10  20  30
```

Answer (score 8):

"Anonymous" subroutines are really similar to regular, named subroutines except that they aren't bound to a name in the symbol table.

```
sub Foo { stuff() }

BEGIN { *Foo = sub { stuff() } }  # essentially equivalent
```

In the second case, the "anonymous" subroutine is created and then bound to the name "Foo" in the current namespace.  The BEGIN block makes it happen at compile time, just like how a named subroutine is treated.  (It's a little more complicated in that the first case gives it a name that will show up in a stack trace.)

Anonymous subroutines are useful any time you want to create a function at run-time.  This is particularly good for "closures" -- functions that "remember" their lexical context.  For example, turning a list into an iterator:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub make_iterator {
  my @list = @_;
  return sub { shift @list }; # new sub that 'remembers' @list
}

my $iter1 = make_iterator( 0 .. 10 ); 
my $iter2 = make_iterator( 'a' .. 'z' );

say $iter1->();  # '0'
say $iter1->();  # '1'
say $iter2->();  # 'a'
```

For a lot more on why anonymous subroutines are useful, I recommend the book [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/) which describes various techniques and applications of functional programming in Perl.

Comment: *aren't bound to a name in the symbol table* -- maybe obvious but does it mean that anon subs can make your program run faster? (I expect them to get compiled once.)

Comment: Compared to compiled function calls, probably not. Compared to method calls, maybe, but methods are cached by the runtime for efficiency.  I wouldn't look to anonymous subs as a performance optimization, but who, knows.  Benchmark it and see.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the aspect of *function calls* being compiled. BTW: a really great book recommendation you included there :)

Answer (score 8):

I talk about anonymous subroutines and why you would use them in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/). In short, you start thinking about behavior as just another form of data just like you think about strings or numbers. When you are comfortable with that idea, you can do some pretty amazing things because you can push off a lot of decisions to very late in the program and you don't have to contort your code design to deal ahead of time with every situation that might show up.

You can write code knowing that you are going to run a subroutine, only you don't know which one yet. You trust the previous steps to work that out for you. Once you can do that, you're on another level of programming that feels like you're writing code to create your program for you. Some programming problems become much easier to solve this way.

And, like every other feature, you can take this too far or use it inappropriately.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical answer for anonymous subroutine is usually the numeric sorting of an array :

```
my @sorted_array = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;
```

The `{ $a <=> $b }` represents an anonymous subroutine.

Comment: The [block after `sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) is indeed very close to an anonymous sub, but not the same: a block is only a part of a sub. Without the `sub` keyword, you don't get a sub, see [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#SYNOPSIS)

Answer (score 1):

First: sub thing is a sub.  my $thing=sub... is a sub reference stored in a variable.

Second: There's a subtle usage difference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub xx {
  my $zz=1;

   sub yy {
      print $zz;
   }
}


perl tmp.pl
Variable "$zz" will not stay shared at tmp.pl line 8.
```

Change [`sub yy`...] to [`my $yy = sub {`...] or [`local *yy = sub{`...] and the complaint goes away.

Also, to be honest, references-to-subs are just easier to deal with, much the same as @x=(1,2,3) versus $x=[1, 2, 3].

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's an example from my [rewrite of Nasm's version.pl](http://repo.or.cz/w/nasm/perl-rewrite.git?a=blob;f=perl/version.pl)

```
# jump table to subroutines / variables
my %jump = (
  id     => 'id',
  xid    => 'xid',
  hex_id => 'xid',

  h      => \&h,
  mac    => \&mac,
  sed    => \&sed,
  make   => \&make,
  nsis   => \&nsis,

  perl   => \&perl,
  dump   => \&perl,
  yaml   => \&yaml,
  yml    => \&yaml,
  json   => \&json,
  js     => \&json,

  help   => \&help,
  usage  => sub{
    require Pod::Usage;

    Pod::Usage::pod2usage(
      "run perldoc $0 or pod2text $0 for more information"
    );
  }
);
```

Basically the only reason I can think of is for calbacks, or for a jump table.