# Shared variables in the context of subroutines vs anonymous subroutines

Tags: perl

I saw this bit of code in an answer to another post: [Why would I use Perl anonymous subroutines instead of a named one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834590/why-would-i-use-perl-anonymous-subroutines-instead-of-a-named-one), but couldn't figure out exactly what as going on, so I wanted to run it myself.

```
sub outer
{
  my $a = 123;

  sub inner
  {
    print $a, "\n"; #line 15 (for your reference, all other comments are the OP's)
  }

  # At this point, $a is 123, so this call should always print 123, right?
  inner();

  $a = 456;
}

outer(); # prints 123
outer(); # prints 456! Surprise!
```

In the above example, I received a warning: "Variable $a will not stay shared at line 15.
Obviously, this is why the output is "unexpected," but I still don't really understand what's happening here.

```
sub outer2
{
  my $a = 123;

  my $inner = sub
  {
    print $a, "\n";
  };

  # At this point, $a is 123, and since the anonymous subrotine 
  # whose reference is stored in $inner closes over $a in the 
  # "expected" way...
  $inner->();

  $a = 456;
}

# ...we see the "expected" results
outer2(); # prints 123
outer2(); # prints 123
```

In the same vein, I don't understand what's happening in this example either.  Could someone please explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to do with compile-time vs. run-time parsing of subroutines. As the [`diagnostics`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldiag) message says,

> When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
>       the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
>       call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
>       outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
>       longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
>       variable will no longer be shared.

Annotating your code:

```
sub outer
{
  # 'my' will reallocate memory for the scalar variable $a
  # every time the 'outer' function is called. That is, the address of
  # '$a' will be different in the second call to 'outer' than the first call.

  my $a = 123;


  # the construction 'sub NAME BLOCK' defines a subroutine once,
  # at compile-time.

  sub inner1
  {

    # since this subroutine is only getting compiled once, the '$a' below
    # refers to the '$a' that is allocated the first time 'outer' is called

    print "inner1: ",$a, "\t", \$a, "\n"; 
  }

  # the construction  sub BLOCK  defines an anonymous subroutine, at run time
  # '$inner2' is redefined in every call to 'outer'

  my $inner2 = sub {

    # this '$a' now refers to '$a' from the current call to outer

    print "inner2: ", $a, "\t", \$a, "\n";
  };

  # At this point, $a is 123, so this call should always print 123, right?
  inner1();
  $inner2->();

  # if this is the first call to 'outer', the definition of 'inner1' still
  # holds a reference to this instance of the variable '$a', and this
  # variable's memory will not be freed when the subroutine ends.

  $a = 456;
}
outer();
outer();
```

Typical output:

```
inner1: 123     SCALAR(0x80071f50)
inner2: 123     SCALAR(0x80071f50)
inner1: 456     SCALAR(0x80071f50)
inner2: 123     SCALAR(0x8002bcc8)
```

Comment: “Parsing” is probably the wrong word here, but “compilation” seems slightly wrong too: IIRC, for closures the compiled code is just combined to a new environment/scope, resulting in a new CV, whereas named subs are never rebound to a new scope (without a redefinition).

Answer (score 1):

You can print \&inner; in the first example (after definition), and print $inner; in second.

> What you see are hex code references which are **equal** in first example and differ in second.
>   So, in the first example inner gets created only once, and it is always closure to $a lexical variable from the first call of the outer().