# How to pass entire subroutine into hashtable data using perl?

Tags: perl, hashtable, subroutine

I have the following subroutine which i should pass the routine as hashtable and that hashtable should be again called inside another subroutine using perl?

**input file(from linux command bdata):**

```
NAME     PEND RUN SUSP JLIM JLIMR   RATE   HAPPY
achandra 0    48  0    2000 50:2000 151217 100%
agutta   1    5   0    100  50:100  16561  83%
```

**My subroutine:**

```
sub g_usrs_data()
{
    my($lines) = @_;    
    my $header_found = 0;
    my @headers = ();
    my $row_count = 0;
    my %table_data = ();
    my %row_data = ();

    $lines=`bdata`; 
    #print $lines;
    foreach (split("\n",$lines)) {
        if (/NAME\s*PEND/) {
            $header_found = 1;  
            @headers =split;
        }
        elsif (/^\s*$/) 
            {
                $header_found=0;
            }
            $row_data{$row_count++} = $_;
            #print $_;
        }
```

**My query:**

How can i pass my subroutine as hash into another subroutine?

*example:*
g_usrs_data() -> this is my subroutine .

the above subroutine should be passed into another subroutine (i.e into usrs_hash as hash table)

*example:*
create_db(usrs_hash,$sql1m)

Comment: What do you mean by "_pass my subroutine **as hash**_"? You can pass subroutine as coderef, but what is "_as hash_"? Also, you show `g_usrs_data` but then in "_example_" use `usrs_hash` and `create_db`?  What does `,$sql1m` mean? The "_example_" is completely unclear, and not correct code.  Can you clarify?

Comment: i want to pass same subroutine function(i.e g_usrs_data) into another subroutine with different name(i.e usrs_hash) using hashes.@zdim

Comment: OK ... what do you mean by "_using hashes_"?  You can pass subroutines around using _code reference_, which is, like every reference, a scalar.  I don't understand what hashes have to do with that.  (You _can_ make that code reference be a value of a hash pair, if that's what you mean.)

Comment: using hashes mean in hashtable format and $sql1m is another variable.You can skip of that thing@zdim

Comment: I posted a basic way to pass code around.  Let me know if that is what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Subroutines can be passed around as *code references*.  See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

An example with an anonymous subroutine

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $rc = sub { 
    my @args = @_; 
    print "\tIn coderef. Got: |@_|\n"; 
    return 7;  
};             # note the semicolon!

sub use_rc {
    my ($coderef, @other_args) = @_; 
    my $ret = $coderef->('arguments', 'to', 'pass');
    return $ret;
}

my $res = use_rc($rc);
print "$res\n";
```

This silly program prints

```
        In coderef. Got: |arguments to pass|
7
```

Notes on code references

- The anonymous subroutine is assigned to a scalar `$rc`, making that a code reference
- With an existing (named) sub, say `func`, a code reference is made by `my $rc = \&func;`
- This `$rc` is a normal scalar variable, that can be passed to subroutines like any other
- The sub is then called by `$rc->();` where in parenthesis we can pass it arguments

Note that the syntax for creating and using them are just like for other data types

- As anonymous assign by `= sub { }`, much like `= [ ]`  (arrayref) and `= { }` (hashref)
- For a named sub use `&` instead of a sigil, so `\&` for sub vs. `\@` (array) and `\%` (hash)
- They are used by `->()`, much like `->[]` (arrayref) and `->{}` (hashref)

For references in general see [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Subroutines are covered in depth in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

---

See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834590/why-would-i-use-perl-anonymous-subroutines-instead-of-a-named-one)  on anonymous subs, with a number of answers.

For far more see [this article](https://www.masteringperl.org/2014/02/naming-anonymous-subroutines/) from *Mastering Perl* and [this article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/09/enchant-closures-for-better-debugging-output/) from *The Effective Perler*.