# How to call subroutine in perl using variable name

Tags: perl, call, subroutine

Let say I have one array that contains all subroutine name and I want to call all one by one.

```
foreach $sub (@arr){
      print "Calling $sub\n";
       #---How to call $sub?----
       &$sub;  ## will not work
}
```

Comment: `(\&$name)->(@args)`

Answer (score 11):

Your code is correct in general, but you need to turn off [`strict 'refs'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) to make Perl allow you to use variable content as code refs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo { print "foo" }
sub bar { print "bar" }

my @arr = qw/foo bar/;
foreach my $sub (@arr) {
    no strict 'refs';
    print "Calling $sub\n";

    &$sub();
}
```

The output here is:

```
Calling foo
fooCalling bar
bar
```

I've also added parenthesis `()` after the call. That way we pass no arguments to `%$sub`. If we do not those, the `@_` argument list of the current subroutine will be used.

---

However, you should probably not do this. Especially if `@arr` contains user input, this is a big problem. Your user can inject code. Consider this:

```
my @arr = qw/CORE::die/;
```

Now we get the following output:

```
Calling CORE::die
Died at /home/code/scratch.pl line 1492.
```

Oops. You don't want to do this. The `die` example is not very bad, but like this you could easily call code in some different package that wasn't intended.

It's probably better to make a [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). There is a whole chapter about those in *Higher Order Perl* by Mark Jason Dominus, which you can [download for free on his website](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

It basically means you put all the subs into a hash as code references, and then call those in your loop. That way you can control which ones are allowed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub baz { print "baz" }

my %dispatch = (
    foo => sub { print "foo" },
    bar => sub { print "bar" },
    baz => \&baz,
);

my @arr = qw/foo bar baz wrong_entry/;
foreach my $sub ( @arr ) {
    die "$sub is not allowed" 
        unless exists $dispatch{$sub};

    $dispatch{$sub}->();
}
```

This outputs:

```
foobarbaz
wrong_entry is not allowed at /home/code/scratch.pl line 1494.
```

Comment: I gave the man a fish, you taught him how to fish. +1

Comment: @Zaid oh, there are two more answers. I didn't see them yet. I was just busy hacking down half a blog post in here again... :D

Comment: HI simbabque. Thanks. I was not knowing that.  In my case users are not providing subroutine name in arguments but good info.

Comment: @Zaid I assumed the OP does not have `use strict` because there was no `my sub` in the loop. In that case, the OP's code works. With `strict` turned on however, `strict 'refs'` needs to be disabled.

Comment: Am I getting downvoted because it's too much text?

Answer (score 8):

You want to do that using *code references*.

```
foreach my $sub (@arr) 
{
    $sub->();
}
```

where `@arr` contains scalars such as

```
my $rc = sub { print "Anonymous subroutine\n" };
```

or

```
sub func { print "Named sub\n" }
my $rc = \&func;
```

You can manipulate these scalars as you would any other, to form your array. However, it is more common and useful to use them as values in a hash, creating a *dispatch table*.

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html), and (for example) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457255/how-to-pass-entire-subroutine-function-into-hashtable-data-using-perl/41457598#41457598) and links in it for comments and details.